# Case-sensitive MatchesMask alternative in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I use the code below for detecting desired files:

```
uses Masks;
 
begin
  if MatchesMask(MyFilename, '*.Exe') then
  begin
    // Do Something
  end;
end;
```

However, as stated in [the official documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask), MatchesMask is case-insensitive.

Is there any **case-sensitive** way to detect filenames using wildcards? (I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 VCL)

Comment: By all means: if you only check against a specific suffix then you can use `if Copy( MyFilename, Length( MyFilename )- 3, 4 )= '.Exe'` right away.

Comment: @AmigoJack: I'd write that `MyFilename.EndsWith('.Exe')`.

Comment: @AmigoJack or `if ExtractFileExt(MyFilename) = '.Exe' then` https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFileExt

Comment: I'm curious what all those do under the hood (and how robust they are)...

Comment: Their is regex tool in delphi, Tregex if i remember well

Answer (score 0):

that's fine ?

Maybe you can do This. Convert all to Uppercase.

```
uses Masks;
 
begin
  if MatchesMask(Upper(MyFilename)), Upper('*.Exe')) then
  begin
    // Do Something
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is already case insensitive. I want case sensitive.